# Parsing an XMl that contains "&pound;"

Tags: c#, xml

I am parsing an xml document that is not well formed, it contains "&" in it, and the parsing is not correct it a node has "&" in it.

e.g. `<abcnode>&pound;70.00-&pound;90.00</abcnode>`

When I try to get this node's value it returned "70.00-".

I have no control over this xml so I will have to parse this malformed xml.

I am using `XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(url);` to load xml from url.

I can get the xml replace the `&pound;` to solve my problem, but this xml can be very large so I do not want to download the file to replace invalid characters (for performance reason).

Is there a way to parse this xml using `XmlTextReader`?

Comment: I hate to be picky, but there is no such thing as "an xml document that is not well formed". If it's not well formed, then it's not XML. If there's a definition of the entity `&pound;` then the document is well-formed XML; if there's no such definition then it's not well-formed and not XML.

Answer (score 2):

`XmlTextReader` will take a `TextReader` argument to read from, so you might be able to implement a class that inherits `TextReader`, override all the `ReadXXX()` methods and repair the invalid characters in the overrides.

**EDIT** Alternatively you could hack the XML's `DOCTYPE` as it is read to add `<!ENTITY pound "&#163;">`, which should make the rest of the document well-formed. There's probably another trick to add the entity to the `XmlTextReader` itself without resorting to modifying the XML at all but I'm not aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether your are right in saying that this isn't well-formed? Perhaps it's parsing correctly but constructing a DOM tree in which the entities appear explicitly as nodes, and your application code is ignoring the entity nodes?